# different compiler behavior when adding bytes

Tags: java

```
byte b1 = 3;
byte b2 = 0;

b2 = (byte) (b2 + b1);  // line 3
System.out.println(b2);

b2 = 0;
b2 += b1;               // line 6
System.out.println(b2);
```

On line 3, it's a compiler error if we don't typecast the result to a byte -- that may be because the result of addition is always int and int does not fit into a byte. But apparently we don't have to typecast on line 6. Aren't both statements, line 3 and line 6, equivalent? If not then what else is different?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the two lines are equivalent - but they use different parts of the language, and they're covered by different parts of the JLS. Line 3 is the normal + operator, applied to bytes which have been promoted to `int`, giving an `int` result. That has to be cast before you can assign it back to a `byte` variable.

Line 6 is a compound assignment operator as described in [section 15.26.2 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.26.2):

> At run time, the expression is evaluated in one of two ways. If the left-hand operand expression is not an array access expression, then four steps are required:
>
> - First, the left-hand operand is evaluated to produce a variable. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the same reason; the right-hand operand is not evaluated and no assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, the value of the left-hand operand is saved and then the right-hand operand is evaluated. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the same reason and no assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, the saved value of the left-hand variable and the value of the right-hand operand are used to perform the binary operation indicated by the compound assignment operator. If this operation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the same reason and no assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, **the result of the binary operation is converted to the type of the left-hand variable**, subjected to value set conversion (§5.1.13) to the appropriate standard value set (not an extended-exponent value set), and the result of the conversion is stored into the variable.

It's the last part (as highlighted) that makes it different.

In fact, the start of the section shows the equivalence:

> A compound assignment expression of the form *E1 op= E2* is equivalent to *E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2))*, where *T* is the type of *E1*, except that *E1* is evaluated only once.

Comment: No more questions, your honor.

Comment: feeling good to have my first question answered by Jon Skeet :)

Answer (score -2):

Java made a mess on operations and conversions involving integral types. The best advice is, use `int` whenever you can. Avoid `byte/short/char`, explicitly convert them to `int` before any calculation.

Comment: Why would you post this 2 hours after Jon Skeet gave a very thorough explanation of how the "mess" works? Sometimes using types other than `int` makes sense.