# Java operators interesting issue

Tags: java, operators

The question is:

Why in this case i get compilation error in Java?

```
byte x = 0;
x = 128;
```

But this is legal:

```
x+= 999l;
```

I use eclipse, jdk 7.

Thank You

Comment: What exactly are you trying to ask, the respective code blocks have nothing in common besides having a variable x?

Comment: He means that x is byte as well in the second case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first one:

```
byte x = 0;
x = 128;
```

A byte is a signed integral type, 8-bits wide, and can express the range of `-128` to `+127`.

`x = 128` means "assign `x` to `128`", and by default, `128` is of type `int`, so you're trying to assign an `int` to `byte` which would cause `Possible loss of precision` errors, because `int` is wider than `byte`. To get this to work, you would have to explicitly cast the value of `128`.

```
byte x = 0;
x = (byte)128; // x is now -128.
```

For your second example, adding values to `x` is fine, but you just overflow the values.

```
byte x = 0;
x += 999L; // don't really need the long qualifier here
// x is now -25.
```

Answer (score 4):

`byte` is signed and can only hold a maximum value of `127` and a minimum value of `-128`, that is why the first case gives you a compile error.

The second case compiles because and value you add to a 'byte' wraps around, notice that `999 % 128 = 103`, which is in the valid range of a 'byte'

Comment: It doesn't really matter what number he added, addition will never fail to compile; it will just overflow -- as opposed to trying to assign an out-of-range compile-time constant.

Comment: It is interesting, but why? In compiler can see that it it overflows and can forbid it but it doesn't do so..

Comment: @SergeyKucher It is also Marko mentioned, overflow can only happen during addition. Assignment is not addition.

Answer (score 1):

byte has a range of -128 to 127. this x+= 999l; works because it is compound assignment operator. have a look here [possible same or alike question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681201/different-compiler-behavior-when-adding-bytes).

Answer (score 0):

In this first statement `x = 128`, since the byte range is `0-127` in java it requires an explicit cast and hence the compilation error. In the second case it overflows and gets converted to -25 which is in byte range.